# Insert each selected item in a list Android

Tags: java, android, list, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I want to insert each selected item of the ListView in a list, this list is going to be the parameter for a method. Elements in listview are selected by a long click. I'm new at Android, so any help I will really appreciate.

This is my code:

```
listViewToDo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
{

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
          int position, long arg3) 
  {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      return false;
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listViewToDo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
{

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int position, long arg3) 
{
  yourList.add(arg0.getItem(position));

  return false;
} 
});
```

yourList would be a list of whatever items you want to store, whitch are of the same type as items you supplied to the ListView adapter

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> List<View> l = new ArrayList<View>();
>
>
> listViewToDo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
> ```
>
> {
>
> ```
>   @Override   
>   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View
>   arg1, int position, long arg3)    {
>
>   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>        l.add(arg1);
>
>        return false;
> ```
>
> }  });

Answer (score 0):

try this,
      listViewToDo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
     {

```
 @Override
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int position, long arg3) 
{
    ArrayList<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(arg1.getItem(position).getText().toString());
    addToList(list);
  return false;
 } 
 });

  public void addToList(ArrayList<String> list) {
  // get the list here
  }
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you @GVSharma, but I have a question. ArrayList type must be a string or the entity tipe? I don't have clear this. Thank you!

Comment: your wish ...you can take any model class and right getter and setter methods and use it